# pls help to write date to sql from date field instead of automatic date retreiving

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help:
application is saving payment date automatically when submitting form. I have added a column with payment date using datepicker js so that I can select date manually. The issue is that cannot link script to sql.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1heNW6NUqk6exdECb_lAkewYXMskTN2uO?usp=sharing

this is the column added to add date manually:

```
<td style="width:10%">
  <?php 
    if($due == 0 || $due < 0) {
      echo '';
      echo '<input style="display:none" >';
    } else {
      echo '<input name="$paymentdate->paymentdate" id="paymentdate" class="form-control" type="text">';
    }
  ?>
</td>
```

Comment: The name attribute of your input for payment date should probably follow the same convention as all the other input fields. What format is your date picker submitting? What have you tried?

Comment: sql attribute for payment date is $paymentdate, how can i make it work ?

Comment: At the very least I suggest you include at least one more input field from your form. By trying to include the absolute minimum in your question you have removed context.

Comment: the code above is set to post automatically date of submitting payment.  i have added a new column with date to precise exact date of payment  (check script):  but i didnt know what to do with code !! even when i select date and submit stuill gives me today's date.

Comment: this is one more field from the form :    <td style="width:10%"><?php if($invoice->discount > 0) { echo ($invoice->amount - (($invoice->amount/100)*$invoice->discount)); } else { echo $invoice->amount;  }  ?></td>

Comment: That is not an input field. It is just a cell with data. Are there no other input fields in your form? By not including more of your code there is no context for us to understand how it is currently functioning. Your partial inclusion of the  `for` loop is not helpful.

Comment: How are you submitting the data? How are you processing it on the server? Is there a form tag? Do you use Ajax? Is it Get or Post? There's a complete disconnect between the html input and the for loop.

Comment: Submit :                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printDiv-submit-<?=$globalpayment->globalpaymentID?>')"><?=$this->lang->line('global_print')?></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flashClose" style="margin-bottom:0px;" data-dismiss="modal"><?=$this->lang->line('close')?></button>
                        </div>

Comment: public function paymentSend() {
        $retArray['status'] = FALSE;
        $retArray['message'] = '';

        if($_POST) {

Comment: there is more than 600 lines

Comment: Please make these changes/additions in your original question, not in the comments. You still have not included another input field from the form. Is `$paids[$i]['value']` not passed from an input field in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML form you need to pass the payment date in such a way that there is one per invoice row. For `paid` it is -

```php
echo '<input name="paid-'.$invoice->invoiceID.'-'.$invoice->feetypeID.'" class="form-control paid_amount _paid_'.($i -1).'" type="text">';
```

So for your new payment date fields it should probably be something like -

```php
echo '<input name="paymentdate-'.$invoice->invoiceID.'-'.$invoice->feetypeID.'" class="form-control type="text">';
```

The payment date is being set server side by -

```php
'paymentdate' => date('Y-m-d'),
```

and this needs to be changed to take the input from your form but your current question does not include enough information to figure out how the value is being submitted.

Given the update with the files you have linked to I am still not 100% sure how it is functioning so please add the following in the paymentSend() method -

```php
$paids         = $this->input->post('paid');
$weavers       = $this->input->post('weaver');
$fines         = $this->input->post('fine');
// add these three lines
$paymentdates  = $this->input->post('paymentdate');
print_r($paids);
print_r($paymentdates);
```

My best guess without more info would be something like -

```php
'paymentdate' => $paymentdates[$i]['value'],
```

but this does not account for having to format the submitted date as you have not answered my previous questions.

The three additional fields (paymentday, paymentmonth and paymentyear) are completely redundant as these can always be inferred on-the-fly from the paymentdate.

Comment: to see script in details : 
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1heNW6NUqk6exdECb_lAkewYXMskTN2uO?usp=sharing

Comment: tried your guess but had error500

Comment: If it returned a 500 error perhaps you should check your server log to see what the error was. Alternatively you could add some error handling in the script you are editing.

Comment: If you could make the edits and provide the output of the two print_r() calls then we might be able to get somewhere.

Comment: Thank you nnichols for your time, but still same result as it still shows todays date.

Comment: is it possible to check via teamviewer session ?

Comment: Possibly. What OS and version are you running on your local machine?

Comment: im using Windows10

Comment: In that case,can I suggest you open a Quick Assist session with this code - 665349. Sessions only remain available for 10 mins so you'll have to be quick.

Comment: alright thhank you

Comment: what is the link to raise Quick Assist session ticket ?.

Comment: @YOUBI Quick Assist is part of Win10. The session has now expired but here is a new code - 401693